Understanding flat functors
I am trying to understand the definition of internally flat functors. This is for convincing myself about the idea of Diaconescu’s theorem, so I would appreciate any remark in this particular direction.
According to
https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/flat+functor
I have the following two questions.

In the third clause of the definition. It called the condition “freeness”. It seems to me something with this name should be something about injectivity, but why it is called “freeness” here?
It says Yoneda extension is a sort of tensoring with $F$. In which sense does it happen?

I assume the above two questions might actually be quick and has been written down somewhere. Thanks for any answer or reference!

For now, an answer to part 2 of the question. (See https://dalspace.library.dal.ca/bitstream/handle/10222/75671/MichaelLambert2019.pdf?sequence=1 for more information.)
The Yoneda extension is given by left Kan extension along the Yoneda embedding. Now, by (one) definition of Kan extension, this means that $$\mathbf{Set}\bigl(\mathrm{Lan}_{\mathcal{Y}}F(G),x\bigr)\cong[\mathbf{C}^{op},\mathbf{Set}]\bigl(G,\mathbf{Set}(F-,x)\bigr)$$
for all presheaves $F,G:\mathbf{C}^{op}\rightarrow\mathbf{Set}$.
Now, since the right-hand side looks like it contains a Hom-functor, the Kan extension on the left-hand side could be called the tensor product $F\otimes_{\mathbf{C}}G$ in analogy with the classic tensor/hom-adjunction.
